# Move up the UIView containing UITextField and UIButton when Keyboard shows up not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield, subview

In the main view, I've a `UITableView` beneath that I've another view, textInputView that contains a `UITextField` and a `UIButton`.

Move up the `UIView` containing `UITextField` and `UIButton` when Keyboard shows not working.

```
-(void)animateTextField:(UITextField*)textField up:(BOOL)up
{
    const int movementDistance = -224; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? movementDistance : -movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"animateTextField" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    textInputView.frame = CGRectOffset(textInputView.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:NO];
}
```

If I replace the textInputView with the `self.view` it moves up the entire view but that I don't want. I just want to move up the textInputView.

**Here is the view hierarchy**:

[image: view heirarchy]

**Here is my actual view:**

[image]

By the way, I'm using `XCode 6` with `iOS 8` SDK...

Comment: When moveUp:, you want to slide it outside the screen otherwise inside appearing from top, right ?

Comment: No, the subview containing the UITextField is at the bottom of the main view, I just want to slide it up of the keyboard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using the frame for the textInputView, it is different at different times and so you are not getting the desired effect,

Do it like so,

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront: textInputView]
if(up){
  textInputView.frame = CGRectOffset(textInputView.bounds, 0 self.view.bounds.size.height - textInputView.bounds.size.height)
}else{
  textInputView.frame = CGRectOffset(textInputView.bounds, 0 self.view.bounds.size.height)
}
```

Now, I feel that you want to show the input view just above the keyboard when keyboard appears and hide it when keyboard disappears. The preferred way to do is by observing for **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification** and **UIKeyboardWillHideNotification**. It also provides the animation duration and final keyboard frame.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}


- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)note{
  NSDictionary *userInfo = note.userInfo;
  CGRect finalKeyboardFrame = [userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
  NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

  float inputViewFinalYPosition = self.view.bounds.size.height - finalKeyboardFrame.size.height;
  CGRect inputViewFrame = textInputView.bounds;
  inputViewFrame.origin.y = inputViewFinalYPosition;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
    textInputView.frame = inputViewFrame;
  }];

}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)note{

  NSDictionary *userInfo = note.userInfo;
  NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

  CGRect inputViewFrame = textInputView.bounds;
  inputViewFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
    textInputView.frame = inputViewFrame;
  }];

}
```

Comment: it's not working... it returns the frame = (0 440; 320 40); If the y = 440 then it stays at the bottom of the screen... but if I set textInputView.frame = CGRectOffset(textInputView.bounds, 0 self.view.bounds.size.height - 224); the it returns the frame = (0 256; 320 40); that means it moves up but the view is not seen...

Comment: Ok the problem seems to be that the view is to the back. See my edit.

Comment: Printing description of self->textInputView:
<UIView: 0x796bed60; frame = (0 256; 320 40); autoresize = RM+BM; animations = { position=<CABasicAnimation: 0x7961ee90>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x796bedd0>>

Comment: By the way, when keyboard goes down it seems like the view is coming down from the top of keyboard... video link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y24nppcah320x1l/UIView-Keyboard-Issue.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Well this is not the preferred way to do this. You should observe for keyboard appearance and dispappearance. See my edits.

Comment: I tried that before but not working... by the way, I ran again with your code and made an edit. It's working okay in iOS 7.1.4 device (I don't have iOS 8 device) but it's not working in iOS 8 Simulator (View is not showing...) do you know any reason???

Comment: If it runs on iOS 7 then it should run fine on iOS 8. You need to debug it.

Comment: Interestingly my code also works well in device running iOS 7.1.4 (I didn't tried my code in device before) but I don't know why it's not running on iOS 8 simulator...

Comment: Works great except you need to subtract the textInputView height from the final frames

Comment: Wow thanks, I really didn't realize that. I would be happy if you could edit the answer and correct it :)

Answer (score 3):

```
#define kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD    50.0; //change height for textfield

- (void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    CGRect rect = self.textInputView.frame;
    rect.origin.y = 0.0;
    if (movedUp)
    {
        rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    if(!movedUp)
    {
        rect.origin.y = 45.0f;
    }
    self.textInputView.frame = rect;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    self setViewMovedUp:YES];
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self setViewMovedUp:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1.First of all you have to set < UITextFieldDelegate > in your .h file

2.you have to set the delegate self.textfieldname.delegate = self
and then

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];
}

- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    const int movementDistance = kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

i hope it helps

Comment: I don't want to move the entire view... just subview containing the UITextField and UIButton...

Comment: then put textfield and button in a view and shift the view accordingly

Comment: when i ran your code it is running perfectly fine there might be error in some other place

Comment: did you ran it on device running iOS 8 or simulator?

Comment: i ran it on simulator

Comment: Yes, you are right my code works well but in device running iOS 7.1.4 (I don't have iOS 8 device)... it doesn't work in my simulator... restarted Xcode and mac several times but no luck...

Comment: When app is resumed from background its view frame will be wrong

Answer (score 1):

## For IOS Swift

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        animateTextField(textField, up: true)
    }

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        animateTextField(textField, up: false)
    }
func animateTextField (textField:UITextField, up:Bool) {

        var movementDistance = 80

        var movementDuration = 1.0
        var movement = CGFloat(up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance)
        UIView.beginAnimations("anim", context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }
```